# Debugging a program that requires escalated privileges

Tags: neovim, linux, plugin, debugging, sudo

I have written a program in C that needs to access `/dev/input/eventX` programmatically. Running it as `sudo ./a.out` works well, but I am not sure how to debug it (using `nvim-dap` & `cpptools`).

Here is my configuration:

```
local dap = require('dap')

dap.adapters.cppdbg = {
  id = 'cppdbg',
  type = 'executable',
  command = '/home/user/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/OpenDebugAD7',
}

dap.configurations.c = {
  {
    name = "Launch file",
    type = "cppdbg",
    request = "launch",
     program = function()
       return vim.fn.input('Path to executable: ', vim.fn.getcwd() .. '/', 'file')
     end,
    cwd = '${workspaceFolder}',
    stopAtEntry = true,
    setupCommands = {  
      { 
         text = '-enable-pretty-printing',
         description =  'enable pretty printing',
         ignoreFailures = false 
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Running as root because you need access to one file is a bit of an overkill. Better set your machine up so your user can access it. For inspiration, see e.g. [this question on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72437/how-to-grant-non-root-user-access-to-device-files) or [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242222/read-from-dev-input-devices-without-root-privileges) or [this one on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220566/linux-raw-input-without-root-permission).